# Html link (a)'s with different id's to trigger same function for its own container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few div's that have different content hidden, but they have a link with a unique id. How can i make all those buttons to trigger the same function and make it work only for their own container?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#:input[id^='myBtn_']").click(function() {
    showPopup();
  });

  $(".modal-content").click(function() {

    $(this).hide();
    $("#mask").hide();

  });

});

function showPopup() {
  // show the mask
  $("#mask").fadeTo(500, 0.25);

  // show the popup
  $(".modal-content").show();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0, padding 0
}
#mask {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
  z-index: 10000;
}
.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #ffff;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10001;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toptop">
  <h4>test1</h4>
  <div class="someclass">Title</div>

  <a href="javascript:;" id="myBtn test1">Read more...</a>
  <div class="modal" id="myModal test1">
    <div id="mask">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>


  </div>


  <div class="toptop">
    <h4>test2</h4>
    <div class="someclass">Title</div>

    <a href="javascript:;" id="myBtn test2">Read more...</a>
    <div class="modal" id="myModal test2">
      <div id="mask">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: `$("#:input[id^='myBtn_']")` what is `#` doing here? also multiple ID is not allowed. use class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs always need to be unique. Give it a class instead and target that as your event. something like this.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="button" id="myBtn">Read more...</a>

$("a.button").click(function( e ) {
      showPopup( $(this) );
});

function showPopup( element ) {
    // show the mask
    element.next('#mask').fadeTo(500, 0.25);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple ID for any single element. ID is unique and you have to use only one for every element. You can use multiple class for this.
Use like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.myBtn").click(function() {
       $(this).next(".modal").fadeIn(500);
    });

    $(".modal").click(function() {

        $(this).hide();

    });

});
```

```css
* { margin: 0, padding 0}

.modal{
    position: absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
right:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color:#fff;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toptop">
  <h4>test1</h4>
  <div class="someclass">Title</div>

  <a href="javascript:;" class="myBtn test1">Read more...</a>
  <div class="modal" id="test1">
    <div class="mask">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="modal-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>


</div>


<div class="toptop">
  <h4>test2</h4>
  <div class="someclass">Title</div>

  <a href="javascript:;" class="myBtn test2">Read more...</a>
  <div class="modal" id="test2">
    <div class="mask">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="modal-content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>


</div>
```